# Can I use python 2.7 shell with the turtle module?

Tags: python-2.7, turtle-graphics

When I try to use the turtle module with the python 2.7.11 shell, the turtle graphics window that does not respond. Can I use the python 2.7.11 shell with the turtle module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the 2.7.11 python shell it won't let use use the features of the turtle module. Sorry

Comment: Thank you, I'll just use python 3